# Unexpected token : in JSON at position 1

Tags: node.js

Как решить? Это бот вк.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\user\Desktop\JusTone\bot\base\chats.json: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1009:27)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\JusTone\bot\osnovn.js:44:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Comment: Проверьте BOM и пересохраните файл в нужном виде.